# How do I use Swift 2.3 to build my project instead of Swift 3 in Xcode 8?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, swift3

I recently updated my `Xcode` and because of this I can't build my app. I googled a couple of solutions and found out that I need to install a toolchain to use `Swift 2.3` instead of `Swift 3`. And to install a toolchain, I need to use `Carthage`.

[Source:](https://carpeaqua.com/2016/06/17/picking-your-swift-toolchain-from-xcodebuild/)

However, I am using `CocoaPods` for my dependencies and I can't commit to a change now. So my question is:

1. Can I install the toolchain without `Carthage`? If so how?
2. Can I use them both ?
3. Is there any other way?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Tried setting "Use Legacy Swift Language Version." to "No". However my other frameworks (i.e. `Alamofire`) started to show following error:

```
“Use Legacy Swift Language Version” (SWIFT_VERSION) is required to be configured correctly for targets which use Swift. Use the [Edit > Convert > To Current Swift Syntax…] menu to choose a Swift version or use the Build Settings editor to configure the build setting directly.
```

Comment: There is a build setting called "Use Legacy Swift Language Version." "No" means Swift 3 and "Yes" means Swift 2.3. I don't think you need any toolchains; just set that to Yes.

Comment: Tried that but got the error you can see above.

Comment: If you're not ready to upgrade, try installing XCode 7.3.1 in a different directory on your machine. You can use xcode-select to choose this one and build using Swift 2.2 until you are ready to upgrade your pods.

Answer (score 1):

Your project is in Swift 2.2, not Swift 2.3. When you go to the convert menu, you'll have the option of a choosing between Swift 2.3 and Swift 3. Pick Swift 2.3 and run the conversion.